# RESTful copy/move operations?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am trying to design a RESTful filesystem-like service, and copy/move operations are causing me some trouble.

First of all, uploading a new file is done using a PUT to the file's ultimate URL:

```
PUT /folders/42/contents/<name>
```

The question is, what if the new file already resides on the system under a different URL?

**Copy/move Idea 1**: PUTs with custom headers.

This is similar to [S3's copy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/index.html?RESTObjectCOPY.html).  A PUT that looks the same as the upload, but with a custom header:

```
PUT /folders/42/contents/<name>
X-custom-source: /files/5
```

This is nice because it's easy to change the file's name at copy/move time.  However, S3 doesn't offer a move operation, perhaps because a move using this scheme won't be idempotent.

**Copy/move Idea 2**: POST to parent folder.

This is similar to the [Google Docs copy](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#MovingIntoFolders).  A POST to the destination folder with XML content describing the source file:

```
POST /folders/42/contents
...
<source>/files/5</source>
<newName>foo</newName>
```

I might be able to POST to the file's new URL to change its name..?  Otherwise I'm stuck with specifying a new name in the XML content, which amplifies the RPCness of this idea.  It's also not as consistent with the upload operation as idea 1.

Ultimately I'm looking for something that's easy to use and understand, so in addition to criticism of the above, new ideas are certainly welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTTP spec says if the resource already exists then you update the resource and return 200.
If the resource doesn't exist then you create it and you return 201.

Edit:
Ok, I misread.  I prefer the POST to the parent folder approach.  You could also refer to the source file using a query string parameter.  e.g.

```
POST /destination/folder?sourceFile=/source/folder/filename.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant what if the new file already resides on the system at a different URL.  That is, I don't want to re-upload the file.  I just want it relocated.

Comment: We went with a POST to the parent container.  It seemed to be the method that was most easily understood by newcomers.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: You should send the URL params in the Body of the POST

Comment: @Tarion Why?  Using what media type?  What would the benefit be?

Answer (score 7):

To create a new resource you usually use `POST`. This should create a new resource on a URI creates by the Server.

```
POST /folders/42/contents/fileName
<target>newFile</target>
```

What REST says is that with `POST` the new Resource is located in a path determined by the server. This is how copy even works in the (windows) FileSystem. Consider you copy a file to a name that already exists, then the response of the above example could be:

```
<newFileLocation>/folders/42/contents/newFile-2</newFileLocation>
```

A move is then made by first copy then delete. You should not do these two actions in one request.

**Edit:**
I found the book [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do) very good.

Chapter 11 handles the Copy method and recommends the following in 11.1:

> **Problem**    You want to know how to make a copy of an existing resource.
>
> **Solution**     Design a controller resource that can create a copy. The client makes a POST request to this controller to copy the
>   resource. To make the POST conditional, provide a one-time URI to the
>   client. After the controller creates the copy, return response code
>   201 (Created) with a Location header containing the URI of the copy.
>
> **Request**    POST /albums/2009/08/1011/duplicate;t=a5d0e32ddff373df1b3351e53fc6ffb1
>
> **Response**
>
> ```
> <album xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
> <id>urn:example:album:1014</id>
> <atom:link rel="self" href="http://www.example.org/albums/2009/08/1014"/>
> ...
> </album>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

REST is not limited to the default set of HTTP methods. You could use [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) in this case.

Comment: That's an interesting idea!  I'll have to look into this.

Answer (score 1):

For moving, you could

a). copy via PUT with a custom source header followed by a DELETE on the source.

b). DELETE source with a custom move header.

I prefer the latter because it can be atomic and it is clear to the client that the resource was removed from the original collection. And when it GETs the collection of its new location, it will find the moved resource there.

Answer (score 0):

For the move part, just do a combo of Copy (PUT) then Delete if you want to keep it simple.

Comment: It's a fair idea, but it feels like copy and move work essentially the same way here; I'm not sure deconstructing move buys me much.  :-(