# Is all the functions can interrupt in a RESTful way?

Tags: web-services, restful-architecture

The RESTFul mainly basic on this four actions:
`GET,POST,PUT,DELETE`

But if I want to change a `item` from `location A` to `location B`... How can I do so??

Should I have two functions to do so?

`DELETE /item/locationA/1`

`PUT    /item/locationB/1`

Thanks.

Comment: [RESTful copy/move operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017143/restful-copy-move-operations)