# Restful Method + Copy file from one location to another location

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

First of all, i would like to Thank @Darrel Miller. The below question raised from his answer in [RESTful copy/move operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017143/restful-copy-move-operations).

I am trying to construct a restFul service, with multiple resource and one resource in that is - for copying file from one location to another location under same parent directory.

Here are my confusion:

1. Which method to choose for it? POST or PUT.
2. Can we go with URL Params or through Payload?
3. If it is URL Params how it should looks like?
4. And if suppose i need to do this for list of files, Is it still good to go with URL Params?

These are my params

- sourceLocation
- destLocation
- fileName

Thanks in advance!